# How to import bitstreams without handle to dspace?

Tags: dspace

We assume that I want to insert into my DSpace a CD with several files of publications in various formats without handle.

For example:

Mp4
Text
Mp3
Pdf
Jpeg

How to do this in large scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DSpace Simple Archive Format will allow you to build item ingest folders on your server and import those folders as items in DSpace.  A handle will be assigned on import.

https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Importing+and+Exporting+Items+via+Simple+Archive+Format

The following page documents the way that we have used this Simple Archive Format to automate ingest into our repository.

https://github.com/Georgetown-University-Libraries/File-Analyzer/wiki/DSpace-Institutional-Repository-Ingest